# Десериализировать ответ от сервера (json)

Tags: c#, json

Не получается десериализировать json из [API Imgbb](https://api.imgbb.com/)

Делаю так:

```
public class Thumb
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mime { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload"), "POST", param);
    client.UploadValuesCompleted += (s, e2) =>
    {
        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e2.Result);
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Thumb> listThumb = (List<Thumb>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(List<Thumb>));
    
        foreach (Thumb item in listThumb)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.url + "___" + item.filename);
        }
    };
}
```

Ответ получаю такой:

```
{"data":{"id":"kQsvMWQ","title":"ca434bb705ee","url_viewer":"https:\/\/ibb.co\/kQsvMWQ","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/4Pn3J5P\/ca434bb705ee.png","display_url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/4Pn3J5P\/ca434bb705ee.png","size":41470,"time":"1616506259","expiration":"0","image":{"filename":"ca434bb705ee.png","name":"ca434bb705ee","mime":"image\/png","extension":"png","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/4Pn3J5P\/ca434bb705ee.png"},"thumb":{"filename":"ca434bb705ee.png","name":"ca434bb705ee","mime":"image\/png","extension":"png","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/kQsvMWQ\/ca434bb705ee.png"},"delete_url":"https:\/\/ibb.co\/kQsvMWQ\/eae1df4e5c101656e8156876aef02795"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

Пример ответа с сайта:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "2ndCYJK",
    "title": "c1f64245afb2",
    "url_viewer": "https://ibb.co/2ndCYJK",
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/w04Prt6/c1f64245afb2.gif",
    "display_url": "https://i.ibb.co/98W13PY/c1f64245afb2.gif",
    "size": "42",
    "time": "1552042565",
    "expiration":"0",
    "image": {
      "filename": "c1f64245afb2.gif",
      "name": "c1f64245afb2",
      "mime": "image/gif",
      "extension": "gif",
      "url": "https://i.ibb.co/w04Prt6/c1f64245afb2.gif",
    },
    "thumb": {
      "filename": "c1f64245afb2.gif",
      "name": "c1f64245afb2",
      "mime": "image/gif",
      "extension": "gif",
      "url": "https://i.ibb.co/2ndCYJK/c1f64245afb2.gif",
    },
    "medium": {
      "filename": "c1f64245afb2.gif",
      "name": "c1f64245afb2",
      "mime": "image/gif",
      "extension": "gif",
      "url": "https://i.ibb.co/98W13PY/c1f64245afb2.gif",
    },
    "delete_url": "https://ibb.co/2ndCYJK/670a7e48ddcb85ac340c717a41047e5c"
  },
  "success": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

`MessageBox.Show(item.url + "___" + item.filename);` показывает пустоту.

В чем именно может быть проблема? Пробовал убрать `\` из ответа, но все так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<>` - это список (коллекция, массив). В показанном json **нет** ни одной колллекции. Массивы в json заключаются в квадратные скобки. Соответственно, вы получаете пустой список с нулём элементов.

В фигурных скобках в json содержатся объекты.

В Visual Studio можно сгенерировать набор классов по json автоматически. Копируем json в буфер обмена, идём в меню Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes.

Вот упрощённый набор классов, из которого я выкинул всё лишнее:

```
public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public Thumb thumb { get; set; }
}
public class Thumb
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mime { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Получаем нужные данные:

```
var root = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);

var thumb = root.data.thumb;

Console.WriteLine(thumb.url + "___" + thumb.filename);
```

Comment: Как раз таки не было понятно что нужно создавать еще классы `Root` и `Data`, думал хватит только `Thumb`. Спасибо большое.